# Ubuntu, apparmor won't stop and i can't kill docker containers

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Having a bit of a nightmare with apparmor, i can't stop docker containers and apparently it's down to apparmor, which i don't need to be running.

I ran:

> sudo systemctl stop apparmor

But i still can't kill the docker containers, apparenly apparmor is still running:

apparmor module is loaded.

```
64 profiles are loaded.
64 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /snap/core/12603/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/12603/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/core/12725/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/12725/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/core/12821/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/12821/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/core/12834/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/12834/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/core/12941/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/12941/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/14295/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/14295/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/14549/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/14549/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/14978/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/14978/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/15177/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/15177/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/15314/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/15314/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   /{,usr/}sbin/dhclient
   docker-default
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
   snap-update-ns.canonical-livepatch
   snap-update-ns.core
   snap-update-ns.docker
   snap-update-ns.lxd
   snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch
   snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.configure
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.connect-plug-etc-update-motd-d
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.disconnect-plug-etc-update-motd-d
   snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.remove
   snap.core.hook.configure
   snap.docker.compose
   snap.docker.docker
   snap.docker.dockerd
   snap.docker.help
   snap.docker.hook.install
   snap.docker.hook.post-refresh
   snap.docker.machine
   snap.lxd.activate
   snap.lxd.benchmark
   snap.lxd.buginfo
   snap.lxd.check-kernel
   snap.lxd.daemon
   snap.lxd.hook.configure
   snap.lxd.hook.install
   snap.lxd.hook.remove
   snap.lxd.lxc
   snap.lxd.lxc-to-lxd
   snap.lxd.lxd
   snap.lxd.migrate
0 profiles are in complain mode.
20 processes have profiles defined.
20 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/bin/bash (3264412) docker-default
   /usr/bin/bash (3395377) docker-default
   /usr/bin/node (3395450) docker-default
   /usr/bin/cat (3395466) docker-default
   /usr/bin/node (3395467) docker-default
   /var/tests/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver (3395474) docker-default
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome (3395480) docker-default
   /usr/bin/cat (3395485) docker-default
   /usr/bin/cat (3395486) docker-default
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome_crashpad_handler (3395488) docker-default
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome (3395492) docker-default
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome (3395493) docker-default
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome (3395506) docker-default
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome (3395508) docker-default
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome (3395556) docker-default
   /snap/canonical-livepatch/132/canonical-livepatchd (1082983) snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd
   /snap/docker/1767/bin/dockerd (2355402) snap.docker.dockerd
   /snap/docker/1767/bin/containerd (2355545) snap.docker.dockerd
   /snap/docker/1767/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 (3264390) snap.docker.dockerd
   /snap/docker/1767/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 (3395352) snap.docker.dockerd
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

Comment: As a workaround you could try `aa-teardown` to stop all running apparmor processes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to force kill a container using its PID:

```shell
docker inspect container_name
kill -9 container_pid
```